# FindGDAL.cmake: gdal-config not found. Please set it manually

Tags: qt, cmake, qt4, qgis

I am working on QGIS in Qt,Ubuntu. It was working fine before. Now it is saying that,"FindGDAL.cmake: gdal-config not found. Please set it manually". Please Help me to resolve this error. 
The error window in Run CQmake is look like this.

```
GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR=
GDAL_LIBRARY=
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:153 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find GDAL


FindGDAL.cmake: gdal-config not found. Please set it manually. GDAL_CONFIG=GDAL_CONFIG-NOTFOUND
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Thanks

Comment: Is GDAL installed? check using `dpkg -s libgdal1-dev`

Comment: Till yesterday, QGIS was running fine.. But libgdal1-dev is not installed.

Comment: what do you mean by "running QGIS"? executing a compiled application? this is of course different than trying to compile it.

Comment: Actually, I am customizing QGIS Application, It was compiling fine in Qt. Now it is showing above message while opening the project in the Run Cqmake wizard.

Comment: Qt is not allowing me to load QGIS Project also. It is displaying below message.

Comment: Failed opening project '/home/administartor/dev/cpp/QGIS/CMakeLists.txt': Settings could not be restored.

Comment: Thank you m.s.. My problem got solved by installing lib..